Can ceiling joists support the valley rafter?
Unseen roof leaks led to wood rot where the valley rafter landed on the exterior wall top plate. I cut away the rotten wood. This means I cut away not only some length of top plate but also the bottom end of the valley rafter where it rested on the top plate, about eight inches' worth. I replaced the plates readily enough, but now the lower end of the shortened rafter is hanging in space. Obviously that's no good but I can build support columns atop the ceiling joists (2x6s that rest on the walls' top plates) if that isn't a really dumb idea. Simply replacing that rafter is a no go because that's a roof reconstruction and completely out of scope for me at this time.
Not worried about inspection because some year, when I can, I will get an equity loan and replace the roof anyway. At that time some level of rebuild won't be so difficult. Meanwhile I just need some years of stability. Thoughts? Thank you.


You must wear a helmet when working there or you will bet nails in your head/brain and die. Then Use a 2x4 and sister it as temporary solution

given that the load going to be is near the end of the joist it will probably work but really you should use a repair plate to join to a good replacement piece

Yes, I can sister it and use tie plates and add supports on local rafters. I figured something like this might work but I wanted to check if there were any don't-do-its I hadn't thought of. Thsnk you!
